# Submenu no se despliega al montar en el servidor

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Buen dia ,
tengo un problema ya que al montar la aplicacion en el servidor y hacer las pruebas rutinarias de los cambios que se hicieron me percate de que el submenu que en teoria se deberia desplegar , no lo hace, pero si ejecuto el proyecto si me los muestra saben a que se deba?
Ya la probé en varios navegadores, elimine todo lo que se almacena en memoria y aun sigue sin verse.
La app esta hecha en asp mvc ,tiene la plantilla por de

App montada en el servidor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

App corriendo en local desde VB2017
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Parte del html

```html
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class=" dropdown-toggle">Opeacion</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cambio de Precio Articulos", "CambioPrecioArticulos", "Adquisiciones")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Carga masiva de Articulos", "Index", "Adquisiciones")</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
```

CSS agregado para el submenu

```css
/*
    Parte agregada
*/
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

    .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
    }
```

**Actualización**
Solo tenia que agregar la referencia del Css

Comment: Intenta forzar esas clases CSS con `!important`

Comment: Agrega la respuesta en la zona inferior de respuestas, y quita de tu título la palabra resuelto pues así no funciona la plataforma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualización Solo tenia que agregar la referencia del Css